# View gets altered seconds after command was given

Tags: ios, objective-c

This one is driving me nuts..

I have a splitviewcontroller with a navigation controller on the right and a view controller on the left. Both controllers listen to a few notifications for the calendar access to be available. When available I push my navigation controller to the next view controller and update a few cells in my tableview in the left view controller.

Everything works perfectly.. except that the view itself is a few seconds behind on the log!

I.e. when I push my view controller I write a message to the console and 5 to 10 seconds later, my push comes through.

Using 7MB in memory and 0% CPU..

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do UI work from a thread that is not the main thread.

Comment: I agree with @Paul.s , it sure looks like a threading issue. Can you provide us with some code where you are pushing the  view controller?

Comment: @Paul.s: Yess! Thanks for the tip! Just what this newbie needed.. If you copy/post as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to do UI work from a thread that is not the main thread.